# Error compiling Dockerfile to install wikipedia-API in Python

Tags: python, django, docker

I´m trying to compile my Docker but I found the error bellow in my Django project. I tried to include urllib3 and request in my dockerfile but the error is the same.
It´s looks like some about temporary config/cache directory error, but I don´t know how can I fix it in my Django project.

I found this error when I include wikipediaapi in my code:

```
import wikipediaapi
```

```
Matplotlib created a temporary config/cache directory at /tmp/matplotlib-njyb_ktv because the default path (/.config/matplotlib) is not a writable directory; it is highly recommended to set the MPLCONFIGDIR environment variable to 
a writable directory, in particular to speed up the import of Matplotlib and 
to better support multiprocessing.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/pythondjangoapp/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    path('', include('app.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/app/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/app/app/views.py", line 30, in <module>
    import wikipediaapi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wikipediaapi/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six'
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8:8.3

WORKDIR /app

COPY Pipfile* /app/

## NOTE - rhel enforces user container permissions stronger ##
USER root
RUN yum -y install python3
RUN yum -y install python3-pip wget

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip==21.0.1 \
  && pip3 install --upgrade pipenv==2020.11.15 \
  && pipenv install --system --deploy

RUN pip3 install wordcloud
RUN pip3 install requests
RUN pip3 install urllib3
RUN pip3 install wikipedia-API


USER 1001

COPY . /app

ENV PORT 3000

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "start"]
´´´
```

Comment: Try using `RUN pip3 install six wikipedia-API --force`

Comment: This fix my problem, thanks @TarunLalwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with installation getting corrupted for package `six`. You can overcome the issue by forcing reinstallation

```
RUN pip3 install six wikipedia-API --force
```